# Compare multiprocessing outputs using queue (Python)

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I need to run command1 and command2 at the same time(in parallel) until output of them matches.
For Example the while loop in consumer should break in the third iteration where command1 = 9 and command2 = 9.
I have the above code using multiprocessing. What I am doing wrong ? Any help is appreciated.

EDIT : I took the suggestion given here to make two pools, but the output is running into an infinite loop.
I get the following output

results match

results match

results match

Can anyone explain how is the dataflow occuring here ?

```
import multiprocessing 


def producer1(q1):
    a = [1,2,3,4,5]

    for i in a:
        command1 = i*i 
        q1.put(command1)

def producer2(q2):
    b = [6,7,3,4,5]
    
    for j in b:
        command2 = j*j 
        q2.put(command2)
        
def consumer(q1,q2):
    result1 = q1.get()
    result2= q2.get()
    while True:
        if (result1==result2):
            print("results match")
            break

q1 = multiprocessing.Queue()
q2 = multiprocessing.Queue()

for _ in range(5):
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=consumer, args = [q1,q2])
    
    p1.start()
    producer1(q1)
    producer2(q2)
    print(q1)

p1.join()
```

Comment: The elements are placed onto the queue _in order_. So the elements on it will be: [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 9, 16, 25]. Your test in `consumer` cannot succeed.

Comment: every command should have own queue and then you may get `command1 = 9` and `command2 = 9` at the same time. Or you would have to run both command in the same loop - and run `q.put(command2)` directly after `q.put(command1)` but this way you can't run commands in separated processes. You have to use two questes.

Comment: That makes sense to have separate queues for each command . But that means I need to have two different processes in two different functions ?

Answer (score 0):

You've got an infinite loop because you read from the queues *outside* the infinite loop, and never reassign `result1`/`result2`. You want:

```
def consumer(q1,q2):
    while True:
        result1 = q1.get()  # Reading inside the loop
        result2 = q2.get()
        if result1 == result2:
            print("results match")
            break
```

The other issue (not for correctness, just for actually comparing patterns) is that your producers run one after the other, so in practice, `producer1` must always run to completion (populating the queue completely) before `producer2` begins running, and `consumer` is stuck waiting until `producer2` runs, it can't begin meaningful processing at all while `producer1` is running. Simplest approach is to put (at least) one producer in its own `Process`:

```
for _ in range(5):
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=consumer, args = [q1,q2])
    multiprocessing.Process(target=producer1, args=(q1,), daemon=True).start()
    p1.start()

    producer2(q2)  # May as well let main process run this

p1.join()
```

Making both producers `daemon` `Process`es would allow your main process to short-circuit; as soon as the consumer is done, it can exit, and the producers die automatically (with `producer2` run in the main process, it has to finish even if `consumer` is done).

And on further checking, you have a third problem. After the first loop, if `consumer` *doesn't* find a match (for real code, I doubt you have hard-coded entries with guaranteed matches) you'll launch a second `consumer` while the first is still running, and now you've got race conditions; the first consumer might consume all the odd values from `q1` and the even values from `q2`, rather than the paired up values, while the second gets the others, and even if a match exists you wouldn't find it (and similarly, a non-existing match might be found if the same values occur unpaired, but the consumer desyncs between queues and matches them up).

In practice, I'd probably go for launching your producers in worker processes, and having the main process act as a single consumer, e.g.:

```
import multiprocessing 
import queue

def producer1(q1):
    a = [1,2,3,4,5]

    for i in a:
        command1 = i * i 
        q1.put(command1)

def producer2(q2):
    b = [6,7,3,4,5]
    
    for j in b:
        command2 = j * j 
        q2.put(command2)
        
def consumer(q1,q2):
    while True:
        result1 = q1.get()
        result2 = q2.get()
        if result1 == result2:
            print("results match")
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':  # Guard required for correctness when start method isn't fork
    q1 = multiprocessing.Queue()
    q2 = multiprocessing.Queue()

    for _ in range(5):
        p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=producer1, args=(q1,))
        p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=producer2, args=(q2,))
        p1.start()
        p2.start()
        try:
            consumer(q1, q2)
        finally:
            p1.join()
            p2.join()
        print(q1)
        # Optionally drain queues before next run so matches from last run not
        # processed by consumer
        for q in (q1, q2):
            try:
                while True:
                    q.get_nowait()
            except queue.Empty:
                pass
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment and explanation ShadowRanger.
I tried and ran it , it works only when there is a match in the two lists. 

If there is not then the script runs into an infinite loop .
It gets stuck in that while loop

Comment: @hitman99: Well, that's kind of unavoidable in your current design. You used `get` calls that don't use timeouts, so they block forever when they run out of input, and even if they didn't, the inner loop is infinite barring a match. So you need to decide how to handle this. You could use timeouts, so if no empty queue gets a new item in a certain amount of time, it raises `queue.Empty`. You could have the producers explicitly put a sentinel object in the queue (e.g. `None` if not a valid value otherwise) when they finish, and have `consumer` check for the sentinel and `break` if it's seen.

Comment: Point is, you need to decide what you want to do to fix that case, and it needs to be something that works in a parallel context. There's no one correct answer.